# Issue with tableview method func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9

I am using the method

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{ 
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //Do something
    })
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "More" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        //Do something
    })
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [delete, more]
}
```

I also included

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // you need to implement this method too or you can't swipe to display the actions
        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    return true
}
```

and when I swipe right or left the buttons I created are not showing up. I tried putting override on the editactionforrowatindexpath but then i get an error saying method does not override any method from its super class

Comment: put a break point and check it the function is called or not
? if not then check your delegate is properly set or not !!

Comment: im using uitableviewdelegate and uitabledatasource and the function is not getting called im not sure why @Pushp

Comment: have you already set ? if yes ? then how? proagrametically or using storyboadrd?

Comment: have you given datasource and delegate by drag and drop to controller???

Comment: I set it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your implementation. The function is not getting called is because the delegate and datasource methods are not called properly.

You can connect the delegate and datasource methods by programatically or via storyboard.

When you are implement the tableview programatically You need to add **UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate** in class declaration and connect the delegates using this code.

```
          yourTableView.datasource = self
          yourTableView.delegate = self
```

If you are implement tableview through storyboard you just need to connect the delegate and data source method by dragging

[image: Connect delegate and datasource methods via storyboard]

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not being called

Comment: I did it programmatically

Comment: Can you share the class that you are using tableview.